# Type.InvokeMember on instance

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I call InvokeMember on an instance?

For example, if I want to call the method `MyMethod()` with the argument `"argument string"` of an instance:

```
MyObject myInstance = MyObject.GetObject();

// ?
```

I've tried this:

```
myInstance.GetType().InvokeMember("MyMethod",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public,
    null,
    null,
    new Object[] { "argument string" })
```

but it does not work, complaining that MyObject doesn't have MyMethod, and indeed it is an instance method, not a class method, so I think it's trying to invoke it as a static method.

Any help?

Answer (score 6):

Your second `null` should be the target of the invocation:

```
myInstance.GetType().InvokeMember("MyMethod",
    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public,
    null,
    myInstance,
    new Object[] { "argument string" })
```

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx) for more details.

Comment: +1 This article discusses it too: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0400__Reflection/Invokemembermethodwithcreatedinstancefromreflection.htm

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(MyObject).GetMethod("MyMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
method.Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { "argument string" });
```